# Why do we have $\bigvee_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}T^i\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Y=\left\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\right\}, X=\prod_{-\infty}^{\infty} Y$ and let $T$ be the left shift. Let $A_i=\left\{\left\{x_k\right\}: x_0=i\right\}, 0\leq i\leq k-1$. Then $\xi=\left\{A_0,\ldots,A_{k-1}\right\}$ is a partition of $X$.

For ease notation, let $\mathcal{A}$ denote $\mathcal{A}(\xi)$, the sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the product-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ which contains all elements that are unions of elements in $\xi$.

It is said, that **by definition of the product$-\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$,** we have
$$
\bigvee_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}T^i\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}.
$$

I dont see how this identity follows by the definition of the product-$\sigma$-algebra.

I guess this is because

$$
\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\left\{p_j^{-1}(A_j): A_j\in\mathcal{P}(Y), j\in I\right\}),
$$

with $p_j$ being the $j$th projection,
i.e. it is the sigma-algebra generated by the cylinder sets. And if I see it right, the expression on the left side of the equation is nothing else but the smallest sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal{B}$ containing this generator.

Or maybe one can say that $\bigvee_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}T^i\mathcal{A}$ is the sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{B}$ generated by $\left\{T^i\mathcal{A}\right\}_i$ and I guess this is just $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of the product-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair It is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of all cylinder sets, just as I wrote above.

Comment: Okay. from how you phrased this, I assumed that was a result about $\mathcal B$ instead of its definition. Since the claim was the desired result was an immediate consequence of the definition, I was wanting the definition used.

Comment: Part of your confusion may be because you are using $A_i$ to mean two completely different things in this post. First it is a specific set of sequences into $Y$, then later it is an arbitrary subset of $Y$ with a meaningless subscript attached. A better definition is $$\mathcal B = \sigma\left(\{p_j^{-1}(N)\ :\ N \subset Y, j \in \Bbb Z\}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

By noting that $T^kA_i = p_{-k}^{-1}(i)$, we see that each $T^kA_i \in \mathcal B$. From this it follows that $T^k\mathcal A \subseteq B$, and therefore that $\bigvee_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}T^i\mathcal{A} \subseteq B$.

Conversely, for any $N\subseteq Y$, we see that $$p_{-j}^{-1}(N) = \bigcup_{i\in N}p_{-j}^{-1}(i) = \bigcup_{i\in N}T^jA_i \in T^j\mathcal A \subseteq \bigvee_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}T^i\mathcal{A}$$

Since $\bigvee_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}T^i\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mathcal B$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the sets $p_{-j}^{-1}(N)$, it must be that $\mathcal B \subseteq \bigvee_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}T^i\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Do we really have that $T^kA_i=p_k^{-1}(i)$? Isn't it $T^kA_i=p_{-k}^{-1}(i)$? This would not change your result but anyway.

Comment: You're right. Since it makes no difference to the argument, I skipped examining that in detail and got the direction wrong. Corrected now.